# Minicolors rails gem not allowing options with input_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the minicolors ruby gem but it doesn't set the options when I use input_field instead of input, which I need to use.

I have `f.input_field :colour, class: "form-control colour", as: :minicolors, input_html: {data: {minicolors: {theme: :bootstrap, position: :right}}}` but this is the html it produces..

```
<div class="minicolors ...">
  <input class="form-control minicolors-input ..." input_html="{:data=>{:minicolors=>{:theme=>:bootstrap, :position=>:right}}}" ...>
  ...
</div>
```

So something is happening, but not what I would expect or what I want.
The options do work however when I use `f.input` but I do not want or need the labels and extras that come with using that instead of `f.input_field`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method signature for `f.input_field` is slightly different from `f.input`, which doesn't really seem to be documented anywhere except the [RDoc](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/simple_form/master/SimpleForm/FormBuilder:input_field) sort of hints at it

> All the given options are sent as :input_html.

So the `:input_html` isn't needed and your `f.input_field` call should look like this

```
<%= f.input_field :title, class: "form-control colour", as: :minicolors, data: {
      minicolors: {theme: :bootstrap, position: :right}} %>
```